# Notification on app shutdown in aws instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a java app running on a aws instance. It gets shutdown when any exception occurs. I want some notification sent to my email when this happens. Can i do it through aws alarms ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not `AWS`-fluent but, with a standard jvm, you might wish to give a look to `java`'s options `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=` and `-XX:OnError=` which both allow you to run an arbitrary system command if an out of memory error or an `Error` occur.

If you want to do the same thing with an `Exception` ... you can't (easily). but you can monitor the process exit status like with `java -cp .... my.MainClass my args || alert "java failure"`

Answer (score 0):

If the AWS instance is on linux you can create a cron job to monitor the process of java application and when the process is stopped send the email. To send mail you can use a python script for that.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has SNS service to send notifications , based on the application triggers messages can be emailed or sent as sms. You could read more about it [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/application-event-notifications.html). Hope this helps